# Graphhopper Set up android

Tags: android, osmdroid, graphhopper

I am new to android and trying to write a simple navigation application in android for a small area for over a month now.
The application would need to have offline routing, therefore Graphhoper seemed perfect since the start. However,I was unable to do the simple setup, and thus i have been playing around with other routing engines (especially Brouter, as I need to add areas to avoid during routing).

The same as one month ago, i am stuck in setting up Graphhoper again. 
I have been trying to follow the instructions on https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/android/index.md

1. I have downloaded Demo APK and installed it on my phone.
2. I have cloned **$ git clone git://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper.git graphhopper**
3. Downloaded the raw openstreetmap file **wales-latest.osm.pbf** and put it under the graphhopper folder.
4. **$ cd graphhopper**
5. **$ ./graphhopper.sh import your-area.pbf**

I am stuck at the fifth stage. It is giving me error as shown in following photo. 
[image: Error]

It would be very useful if someone could tell me where to fix it.
Additionally, I would like to add circular areas to avoid while routing.
I have seen setting infinity weight to a bounding box  to avoid that area. 
Can it be done to have a circle?

Thanks very much

Comment: If you are under windows see our windows instructions: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/core/windows-setup.md and make sure you have git, wget and unzip installed in cygwin (not sure if mingw will work too)

Comment: looks like you need maven and wget available

Comment: thank you guys for your answers. i have used babun to do this. cheers

Comment: @Karussell How do I set vehicle to foot in android? Thanks

Comment: See the answer to your question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796776/graphhopper-route-for-pedestrian-android