# Graphhopper Route for Pedestrian android

Tags: android, openstreetmap, graphhopper, mapsforge

How do i set route type to Pedestrian in Graphhopper android?
I have been using GHRequest.setVehicle() method in android, and it does not work. 
I have tried using "foot", and "bike". None worked. Also, it doesn't work when i changed Algorithms too. Only Dijkstra_BI is working now.

```
   GHRequest req = new GHRequest(fromLat, fromLon, toLat, toLon).
                    setAlgorithm(Algorithms.DIJKSTRA_BI).setVehicle("foot");
```

Thanks in Advance.

The map data that i have contain following files. [image]

I am getting the following error when I used

```
tmpHopp.setEncodingManager(new EncodingManager("foot"));
```

[image]

I have solved this problem thanks to karussell. I will write what i did for the people like me who might face this same problem.

**What I did**

In the graphhopper folder cloned from git, there is a file called **config.properties**. In the 5th line. change it to **graph.flag_encoders=car,foot,bike**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you import the data (on the desktop/server machine) you have to specify the vehicles you need via `graph.flag_encoders=bike,foot,...` in the config.properties or in older versions `graph.flagEncoders=bike,foot,...`

Comment: I am sorry I still don't know how to do that Android. 
I set up the application as instructed for android app and I am trying to build-on from android Demo app.

Comment: Just look into the documentation about how to create the maps for Android

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appreciate it verey much.

Comment: Dear Sir, Could you please advise me on how to add no-go areas using dynamic weight? Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801398/graphhopper-no-go-areas-routing

Could you please tell me how to do the bounding box checks instead of ID checks regarding nopub example? Thanks